# Do I have to repeat my Salah?

Tags: salat, fiqh, practical-islam, sharia, muslim-practices

I was praying and after i did tasleem at the end (I didn’t realize it before tasleem) I realized that I might have prayed 3 rakat instead of four. Do I have to make the sajda of forgiveness or pray again?

Answer (score 0):

two doubts that should not be ignored

1. Doubt after the place, as if doubting praise and surah after entering ruku '.
2. Doubt after the prayer.
   So if you doubted that you recited three rak'ats or four rak'ats after the last salaam of the prayer, you should not pay attention to your doubt. And from the jurisprudential point of view, your prayer is accepted.
   But if you have doubts before the salaam prayer, you should assume that you are 4 rak'ats and say the salaam prayer, and after that you perform one rak'at of the precautionary prayer standing, or two rak'ats sitting.
   You can ask for forgiveness or if you want and you have extra time, repeat your prayers, but according to the jurisprudential law, your prayers have been enough.

http://www.makarem.ir/main.aspx?typeinfo=21&lid=0&catid=45589&mid=258048